# UseMnemonic property of a GroupBox in C#.Net 2010

Tags: c#, controls, properties

I use a GroupBox and its text property is supposed to be "Word1 & Word2".  But it seems the UseMnemonic feature takes effective that the result looks like "Word _Word2".

So how can I disable UseMnemonic feature of a GroupBox? Or any workaround.

(I know there is property UseMnemonic for a Button control, but I cannot find the corresponding property for GroupBox, which sounds very weird to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a second '&' if you want to display '&' instead of '_' (e.g. Word1 && Word2).

Comment: Thanks.  I only tried "\&", but not working.  I don't know why there is no UseMnemonic property for a GroupBox, but it does have the Mnemonic feature.

Comment: NP, I was also surprised to see it does not expose the property and I can't find anything as to why... maybe someone else will be able to enlighten us.

Comment: Personally, I don’t understand the purpose of `UseMnemonic`. Who would ever want to turn mnemonics off, explicitly making a control unusable?